# How to remove region from an Amazon S3 website endpoint url?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, amazon-cloudtrail

I am trying to build a static website with Amazon S3.

I am using east-1 (N. Virginia) as my region but the website getting an error.

http://s3.amazonaws.com/egiig/index.html is my website.

For reference please see-

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/VirtualHosting.html

Comment: Could you share a link with the region that is working?

Comment: I need to create a bucket in another region. Wait a while please.

Comment: http://anup365.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/, here you go...

Comment: I want this as s3.amazonaws.com/anup365/index.html like s3.amazonaws.com/blogbook/index.html

Answer (score 3):

The requests of the form `https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name` are Legacy Path Style requests. See the Legacy Global Endpoint section in the Virtual Hosting [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/VirtualHosting.html)

According to the page:

> For the US East (N. Virginia) Region, the legacy global endpoint can be used for path-style requests.
> For all other Regions, the path-style syntax requires that you use the Region-specific endpoint when attempting to access a bucket

In your case for `anup365` the region is `us-west-1` that's why its showing a permanent redirect error.

For your bucket `egiig`, the region was correct, but you were getting `Access Denied` error, which means `Public access` was not enabled for those files. You can do that similar to `anup365` for `index.html` and the website should be accessible at http://s3.amazonaws.com/egiig/index.html